# Make text fit textbox in Illustrator [VIDEO]. Must have variable font-size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I made this video in Adobe Spark. But I want to do this in Adobe Illustrator:

[image]

Notice that the font size changes dynamically.

It seems it might not be possible in Illustrator: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2344784

Anyone ever see a custom script that does this???

Thanks!

Comment: That's a nice feature in Spark, but it doesn't exist in Illustrator, and I haven't come across any plugins/scripts for it. Perhaps you could [request it as a feature](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests)?  In Spark, the feature called "Capitalize & Fit".

Comment: In fact, I just [added a feature request](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-feature-requests/suggestions/34060360-adobe-spark-capitalize-fit-feature-possible-in) myself, perhaps you could vote for it?

Comment: FWIW, this *is* a feature in both Sketch app and Affinity Designer

Comment: Can you tell me which button this is in Affinity Designer?

Comment: Nice video. It is really funny the way you asked the question. -_n

Comment: You set up constraints... using the constraints studio (palette) look at the Grade UI samples to see examples in use.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible for the scripting api to do anything dynamic (within the GUI). It can only be an action. That means you could make it fill a box once but it wouldn't be dynamic.

It is however possible for the c++ API to do this. But unless you are a full time programmer, working on somebody elses dime, you probably wont want to deal with that. Since full on API code needs to be regularily maintained, every time adobe does a new release somebody needs to recompile all that again.

Comment: "filling a box once" is ok for me. I don't necessarily have to have it update whilst i drag.

Comment: @tdog2 then you could have left the dynamic part out. Ill se what i can do, but im super busy at the moment